# How to use internal class on in inline asp code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to use an internal class in an inline ASP code.

Ex : `<%= MyClass.Method() %>`

It's work fine with a public class, but I can't manage to use this with an internal class even with using `assembly:InternalsVisibleTo`

Is it possible to use an internal class or method in inline code ?

Comment: That method should be  `public` and `static` and the class should be `puplic`.

Comment: @Aria : So, to you, there's no way to do this with an internal class ?

Comment: No, you can not do this by `InternalsVisibleTo` it is used just for another assemblies for testing purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Internal` types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly.

Because `.aspx` page is inherited from `.aspx.cs` code-behind class.

You can only get value by `protected` or `public` in `.aspx.cs` code-behind, otherwise you can't access the field or property.

`InternalsVisibleToAttribute` attribute only represent you can get the Internal class from another assembly, but the key point is `.aspx` will render a page and get value `<%= MyClass.Method() %>` from the code behind- class. there isn't any relationship about another assembly

Comment: Why can I user the same method in the .cs using `assembly:InternalsVisibleTo` and not in the .aspx.cs if it's inherited ?

Comment: `InternalsVisibleToAttribute ` this attirbute only represent you can get Internal class from another assembly, but the key point is `.aspx`  get the value `<%= MyClass.Method() %>` is from the class. there isn't any relationship about another assembly